# Solving transportation problem with real data in csv file using pyomo

Tags: python, pyomo

I'm very new to pyomo, and I'm trying to create my first abstract model (transportation problem) with real data in 3 csv files. These three files can be downloaded from the following links.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zd9Ta1m2xea93XakN5z9Cm1PClz9_h17/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oeiBW9yzL-aLefdrekIchfRrMOguMAaJ/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WSkfZj4OK4yMRwKgW0AXNRhH1JzaBHqy/view?usp=sharing

The mathematical model is as follow:

[image]

I have written down my code based on the tutorial provided by the pyomo documentation, and my codes are as follows.

```
from __future__ import division
from pyomo.environ import *

model = AbstractModel()

model.m = Param(within=NonNegativeIntegers)
model.n = Param(within=NonNegativeIntegers)

model.I = RangeSet(1, model.m)
model.J = RangeSet(1, model.n)

model.c = Param(model.I, model.J)
model.s = Param(model.I)
model.d = Param(model.J)

model.x = Var(model.I, model.J, domain=NonNegativeReals)

def obj_expression(model):
    return summation(model.x[i,j] for i in model.I for j in model.J)

model.OBJ = Objective(rule=obj_expression)

def 1x_constraint_rule(model, j):
    # return the expression for the constraint for i
    return sum(model.x[i,j]  for j in model.J) <= model.s[i]

def 2x_constraint_rule(model, j):
    # return the expression for the constraint for i
    return sum(model.x[i,j] for i in model.I ) >= model.d[j]
```

However, I don't really think that I could figure out how to link this model to real data. Could anyone please kindly offer me some help and guidance. Thanks a lot for your great kindness and help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PYOMO: How to use abstract models with internal data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48184893/pyomo-how-to-use-abstract-models-with-internal-data)

Comment: This links can be helpful:https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/working_abstractmodels/data/

Comment: Are you comfortable using regular python to read csv's?  If so, I **strongly** recommend that you just use python to read your data into dictionaries and then use a `ConcreteModel` and initialize the data from python data sources...much easier in my experience.